# Magento2 /bin/sh: /home/appleserver2/public_html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log: No such file or directory

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron, centos, cronjobs

i have delete magento2 installation by directly deleting the directory and database. however i am getting email in every second and the mail content is as below

/bin/sh: /home/appleserver2/public_html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log: No such file or directory

how can i stop these emails or how can i delete these cron jobs

Comment: try this `php bin/magento cron:remove`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in magento root CLI

```
php bin/magento cron:remove
```

and to do it manually

```
Go -> CLI
```

then enter **crontab -e**

an editor will open and go command out the crons which you want to disable.

For more information about creating, running and stop cron [visit here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

hope this help you

Thanks ...